# Error in Python when including strings in calculations

Tags: javascript, python

I made a calculation in Javascript, and no matter what I try, I just can't get the same result in Python.

Here is the Javascript code that works

=================================================================

```
firstNumber = 56
secondNumber = 22

addResult = firstNumber + secondNumber
subtractResult = firstNumber - secondNumber

console.log(firstNumber + ' + ' + secondNumber + ' = ' + addResult)
console.log(firstNumber + ' - ' + secondNumber + ' = ' + subtractResult)
```

=================================================================

It ends with this result...

=================================================================

```
56 + 22 = 78
56 - 22 = 34
```

=================================================================

And this is the Python code I want the same result from

=================================================================

```
firstNumber = 56
secondNumber = 22

addResult = firstNumber + secondNumber
subtractResult = firstNumber - secondNumber

What next???
```

=================================================================

Everything I try ends with an error, does anyone have an answer to this?

Comment: Can you show us some of the things you tried that errored out?

Comment: The trick for "code that does not work" questions is, to show us the [mcve] that replicates it - so you can be helped. the only error this code throws is for `What next???` and that is clearly no python - The answer would be : take python tutorials to learn the languge - start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: You mean something like `print("{} + {} = {}".format(firstNumber,secondNumber,addResult))`

Comment: This chapter handles creating a calculator and shows print statements - in the "see also" section you find further reading on how to `str.format()` numbers into strings: [create a calculator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Next you just need to do some python string concatenation.  See below!

```
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(firstNumber, secondNumber, addResult))
print('{0} - {1} = {2}'.format(firstNumber, secondNumber, subtractResult))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print:

```
56 + 22 = 78
56 - 22 = 34
```

I would do (python 3.6):

```
firstNumber = 56
secondNumber = 22

print(f"{firstNumber} + {secondNumber} = {firstNumber + secondNumber}")
print(f"{firstNumber} - {secondNumber} = {firstNumber - secondNumber}")
```